# Running elementary on ARM single board computers

Tags: system

Need to know if can run elementary OS on single board computers based on ARM Cortex A series chips, like the Raspberry PI 2, 3. Really like the look and feel of your OS, and would be great if can get it running on ARM based hardware.
Regards,
Vibhas K. Dhingra
vibhas.kdhingra@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

There are no ARM images at the moment.

I recommend Ubuntu Mate for Raspberry PI. With some tweaks you'll get the same user interface like in Elementary OS. For the full Elementary OS experience you need to switch to x86-64.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. So what would be the tweaks that can get Mate to be like elementary ? Would be good to get a somewhat detailed answer.

Comment: For hardware like Raspberry Pi, a lighter weight desktop like Mate will probably run better than elementary's Pantheon desktop environment. That said, you can try these steps to get Mate to look like elementary: http://askubuntu.com/a/697459/486628